# TV show I think, where Aliens are leaving Earth, most people on Earth don't know that they are on Earth

Tags: story-identification, tv

I though it may have been an Outer Limits episode, but I couldn't find it there, this seems to low key for Outer Limits anyhow, maybe more like a Disney type..? Watched it when I was really young, basically, it's based around a teenage kid, in love with a girl, his father is some sort of inventor, and not very good as I remember.

At some point the kid finds out he and his family are all Aliens, and they have to go back to their homeworld, which makes the kid sad as he likes an Earth girl.  I can't remember why they had to leave, I think the government asked them to leave, but it didn't seemed forced, or aggressive.

They boarded a futuristic looking plane, and on the plane the kid discovers the girl he was in love with is also an Alien and on the plane/shuttle/rocket with him, and I remember the parents looking at each other and smiled.

I also remember the father sitting on the plane/shuttle/rocket reading the news paper waiting for the plane/shuttle/rocket to take off.

I also remember the mother consoling the kid, and saying he could get a space scooter, and go to some moon, and the kids was stunned, and said something like "You won't even let me get a motorcycle here"

Time period I would say mid-late 80's possibly maybe early 90's.

Comment: I watched all of the Outer Limits (old and new) a few months ago, and I have to say I can't recall this particular episode.  Could it be twilight zone?

Comment: I am thinking its to calm for a Outer Limits, or Twilight Zone, this didn't seem as dark as those shows were, but I could be remembering wrong :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like the ["Amazing Stories"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088478/) episode ["Moving Day"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0511107/), which has all of the plot elements that you mention. Two other details that I remember:

- The boy was bullied in school; I think he may have been locked inside a locker in one scene.
- When the boy's mother speaks to him in the aliens' native language for the first time, the boy asks how he's supposed to learn that when he even has trouble with French.

Comment: Just to confirm your memory, the review [here](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0511107/reviews-1) mentions the element of the father being an inventor, of the family planning a move, and of the teen boy upset he'll have to leave his best friend Karen; and the brief summary [here](http://www.tv.com/shows/amazing-stories/moving-day-69876/) mentions that it turns out they are moving to another planet.

Comment: I will now have to find away to get those dvd's, that sounds exactly like the show I am looking for.  Wow thanks guys!